# Can't pass a Windows Form to another via constructor

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, constructor, c++-cli

i want to pass the Form1 to Form2 via constructor but it is not working, i guess it is somenthing stupid from my side but i can't figure out what is wrong. I would appreciate some help here.

Here is Form1 containig a richtextbox and a button, which opens the second Form.

```
#pragma once

#include "Form2.h" 

namespace passForm {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    ///
    /// WARNING: If you change the name of this class, you will need to change the
    ///          'Resource File Name' property for the managed resource compiler tool
    ///          associated with all .resx files this class depends on.  Otherwise,
    ///          the designers will not be able to interact properly with localized
    ///          resources associated with this form.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
        public: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox1;
        public: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  open_form2_button;

        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->richTextBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
            this->open_form2_button = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this->richTextBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
            this->richTextBox1->Name = L"richTextBox1";
            this->richTextBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 96);
            this->richTextBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->richTextBox1->Text = L"";
            // 
            // open_form2_button
            // 
            this->open_form2_button->Location = System::Drawing::Point(159, 47);
            this->open_form2_button->Name = L"open_form2_button";
            this->open_form2_button->Size = System::Drawing::Size(89, 23);
            this->open_form2_button->TabIndex = 1;
            this->open_form2_button->Text = L"Open Form 2";
            this->open_form2_button->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->open_form2_button->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::open_form2_button_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->open_form2_button);
            this->Controls->Add(this->richTextBox1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void open_form2_button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


                 Form^ rgForm = gcnew Form2(this);
                 rgForm->Show();
                 //this->Hide(); 
             }
    };
}
```

And here is the Form2 with the problematic constructor

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;


namespace passForm {

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form2
    ///
    /// WARNING: If you change the name of this class, you will need to change the
    ///          'Resource File Name' property for the managed resource compiler tool
    ///          associated with all .resx files this class depends on.  Otherwise,
    ///          the designers will not be able to interact properly with localized
    ///          resources associated with this form.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ otherform;

    public:
        Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //


        }

    public:
        Form2(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ frm1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
            otherform = frm1;  // this assignment is not working


        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnShowResults;
    public: 


    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form2()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->btnShowResults = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnShowResults
            // 
            this->btnShowResults->Location = System::Drawing::Point(88, 108);
            this->btnShowResults->Name = L"btnShowResults";
            this->btnShowResults->Size = System::Drawing::Size(99, 23);
            this->btnShowResults->TabIndex = 0;
            this->btnShowResults->Text = L"Show Results";
            this->btnShowResults->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnShowResults->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form2::btnShowResults_Click);
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnShowResults);
            this->Name = L"Form2";
            this->Text = L"Form2";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form2::Form2_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void Form2_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             }
    private: System::Void btnShowResults_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 otherform->richTextBox1->AppendText("Hello\n");  //richTextBox1 is not recognized


             }
    };
}
```

Please pay attention to following parts

Form1.h

private: System::Void open_form2_button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
             Form^ rgForm = gcnew Form2(this);  
             rgForm->Show();
             //this->Hide(); 
         }
```

and Form2.h

private: System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ otherform;

```
public:
    Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //


    }

public:
    Form2(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
        otherform = frm1;  // this assignment is not working


    }
```

i guess those parts generate the errors.

Note that when i pass to the constructor only the RichTxtBox object everything is working fine.

Comment: Your code is C++/CLi not C++. Please tag your posts appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Example :

Form1.h :

```
#pragma once

#include "Form2.h"

namespace ArrayShallow {

    ref class Form2;

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Description résumée de Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: ajoutez ici le code du constructeur
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Nettoyage des ressources utilisées.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Variable nécessaire au concepteur.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Méthode requise pour la prise en charge du concepteur - ne modifiez pas
        /// le contenu de cette méthode avec l'éditeur de code.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->richTextBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            this->richTextBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(32, 25);
            this->richTextBox1->Name = L"richTextBox1";
            this->richTextBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 96);
            this->richTextBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->richTextBox1->Text = L"";
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(153, 157);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->richTextBox1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private:
        Form2 ^ currForm2;
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object ^sender, System::EventArgs^ e);

    public:
        void SetValue(System::String ^text)
        {
            richTextBox1->AppendText(text);
        }
    };
}
```

Form1.cpp :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace ArrayShallow;

System::Void Form1::Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    currForm2 = gcnew Form2(this);
}

System::Void Form1::button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    currForm2->Show();
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return (0);
}
```

And then in form2.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Form1.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

namespace ArrayShallow {

    ref class Form1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Description résumée de Form2
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private:
        Form1 ^currForm1;

    public:
        Form2(Form1 ^theForm1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: ajoutez ici le code du constructeur
            //
            currForm1 = theForm1;
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Nettoyage des ressources utilisées.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form2()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Variable nécessaire au concepteur.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Méthode requise pour la prise en charge du concepteur - ne modifiez pas
        /// le contenu de cette méthode avec l'éditeur de code.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(135, 107);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form2::button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form2";
            this->Text = L"Form2";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
    };
}
```

Event, in form2.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form2.h"

using namespace ArrayShallow;

System::Void Form2::button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    currForm1->SetValue("Hello\n");
}
```

When you'll execute this code :

[image]

Comment: Just the part witn main function in Form1.cpp should be out. I must say that such of clean C++/CLI code just in books i have seen. And the conclusion is that i have to study a bit more about namespaces and includes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to guess:

I'm sure the assignment is working, but then you do this:

```
 otherform->richTextBox1->AppendText("Hello\n");
```

And that is not going to work, since `System::Windows::Forms::Form` does not have a member `richTextBox1`.

You probably want to define a handle to `Form1`, not `Form`.

```
private: Form1 ^ otherform;
```

On the other hand, I suggest that you use the events mechanism to communicate between forms. The second form fires an event passing the proper arguments, the first form installs a handle to that event and does the appropriate processing.

Comment: Nope, it does not working. With my implementation i take the following:error C2039: 'richTextBox1' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::Form' d:\visualstudio2008projects\training\passform\passform\Form2.h 114

Comment: With your suggestion i take a : error C2039: 'Form1' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms' d:\visualstudio2008projects\training\passform\passform\Form2.h 25

Comment: Sorry, I just replaceed `Form1` in your code. I have updated my answer.

Comment: In Form1.h i have changed line Form^ rgForm = gcnew Form2(this); with Form2^ rgForm = gcnew Form2(this); and in Form2.h i have changed the line private: System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ otherform; with  private: Form1 ^ otherform; . Now i receive among other compiling errors the error C2065: 'otherform' : undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 0):

first, in you Form1 class, add a method who will set your RichTextBox value :

```
public:
    void SetValue(System::String ^text)
    {
        richTextBox1->AppendText(text);
    }
```

Then in your form2, on click button :

```
System::Void Form2::button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    currForm1->SetValue("Hello\n");
}
```

It has yet to do anything to make it compile, is to make an early statement in the Form1 Form2.h file. For example, in the first namespace

```
ref class Form1;
```

it will just do the same in the Form1.h file: declare form2 this way:

```
ref class Form2;
```

Your program works fine with me, if you have any questions, do not hesitate

Comment: thank you for reply. Can you be more specific about those early statements? Can you provide an example maybe?